# conditional statement for profile pages

Tags: conditional-tags, members

I'm using different headers for in my wordpress/buddypress setup and I need a conditional statement for member pages. So everything that comes after mysite.com/members/. How do I do that with something like is_page()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function `bp_is_members_component()`.

Comment: I tried using it like `if (bp_is_members_component()){` but that didn't work.

Comment: Where did you use that conditional check? Tested `bp_is_members_component()` and returns true on members directory page.

Comment: I used it in my header.php. `<?php
if (is_single()){
include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/header-post.php');}
elseif (bp_is_members_component()){
include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/header-post.php');}
else {
include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/header-default.php');}
?>`

Comment: It still returned the default header.

Comment: Tested in header.php and works fine.

Comment: Hmmm ok I'm gonna mark it accepted and figure out what is wrong on my end. Thanks!

Comment: What version of BuddyPress do you use? Maybe there is some issues if you use older version

Comment: I have 1.5.4. I tried using (bp_is_page( BP_MEMBERS_SLUG )) and that didn't work either. For now I just used an include for the header on the home.php which works the same way really.